render output from compositor not matching original color
I did some test on the  blender compositor . There's no 3d object, just a simple image node (I imported some random png file -> https://media.istockphoto.com/id/513821918/photo/close-up-of-a-luxurious-table-corner.jpg?s=612x612&w=0&k=20&c=wT5GL-dH1msU5DdieewhB_aahVTeiSgDgAbesxHdrMo= ) connected to 'file output'. I tried to re render image and see if I can get the same color. But the result is not what I expected. the render is flat compared to original. Colorspace is default (srgb). See image split below ( top is render from blender , bottom is original)

How can I get the proper color output ?

After a render is calculated, in scene-referred linear color space, a view transform is applied, which is generally Filmic or AgX, which compresses the color values into a 0.0 - 1.0 range (and looks like it's washing out colors).
If you save an image as jpg or PNG, this view transform gets embedded in the RGB values.
If you don't want this behaviour you need to set the view transform to "Standard" and look "None".



Depending on what your goal is regarding the Color Management, there are different methods to achieve what you want. Here is one way to do everything in post-processing through the Compositor.
Let's say you want to render the following scene: a sphere with some glowing ring sits on the table from your stock image - which is in sRGB colorspace. First of all the scene, below the sphere is a plane which will be used as shadow catcher later. Here is a comparison between how the scene looks with View Transform set to AgX and Standard (both with Look > None):

The emission ring is quite bright, so I want to use AgX since the saturated purple does not look good in my opinion. So I leave the Color Management at AgX and render the scene now with the shadow catcher enabled. In the Compositor I combine background image and rendered scene by multiplying the background with the Shadow Catcher pass for the shadows and emission and for the sphere above I use an Alpha Over node. The problem is now: I want the original colors of the background image and the AgX colors for the sphere. Using either one of these in the Color Management makes one of the components look incorrect.

Result:

Now there are two possible ways to do this in post-processing: the first would be, you leave the Color Management > View Transform setting to AgX. In the Compositor you set the Color Space of the Image node to AgX Base sRGB, multiply it with the Shadow Catcher pass and then plug it in the Alpha Over node - now the background image has the original colors:

Or you can do all color space conversion in the Compositor which I would suggest, because in my opinion the result of multiplying the Shadow Catcher pass is better this way. For this method, set the Color Management > View Transform to Raw.
But now you have to do a little more: change the Image node's Color Space to Non-Color, the Shadow Catcher pass has to be converted with a Convert Colorspace node set to From: Linear Rec.709 and To: sRGB to match it to the image. The rendered image output needs to be converted now as well if you want it to be AgX, set it to From: Linear Rec.709 and To: AgX Base sRGB.

Note that no matter which version you use, the Color Management > Look is always set to None, not High Contrast or anything like that as this will affect the background image too. If you want to change the contrast of the rendered scene, you can always plug a Brightness/Contrast node (or other adjustment nodes) before(!) the Convert Colorspace node.
