Compositor file output node color override not working
I render out an image sequence in Multilayer EXR by using the File output node for export Denoise render pass but it always comes out in Linear Rec.709 transform Instead of AGX log. (I had set it to AGX log on the color override) wondering if it was a bug or if I did something wrong.


I tried to test the color space of the output file to compare between results from the File output node and manually save the AGX log pretty sure it always comes out in Linear Rec.709


What happens if you set the Color Space on the 2nd screenshot to AgX Log ?

The color doesn't look right kinda discolored. (Added the pic on the 3rd screenshot.)

And what did you plug into the rgba channel ? Either your expectations about color spaces are wrong, or it is indeed a bug.

What happens if you add a Convert Colorspace from AgX Log to Linear Rec.709 at the very end ? Then you get your expected output, no ? I think this behavior is working as expected but I'm not totally sure.

Here I explain a bit about colorspaces and EXR files: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/319514/render-output-from-compositor-not-matching-original-color/319531#319531 The thing is, you cannot really apply Color Management to the output file, since EXR is a linear format and will always store linear data.

The rgba channel is the render result which is a naming I set in the File output node.

If you are rendering in open Exr, the output is going to be linear always, and the you can convert it to a different color space by using a compositor like after effects or davicin resolve

So, the Rec.709 that I've got from the File output node instead of AGX log that I have set in the node properties are the same ?
The point is the auto-save from the File output node always came out to be Rec.709 (I have to set the color space to Rec.709 to preview it normally), But when I tried to save as the same render result by manually save as the image and check the color space override menu to AGX log, the result came out as I expected when I import it in the compositing and set the color space to AGX log. Is that normal ?

So since 4.2 came out a while ago I came back and checked the problem I got in 4.1 Now the result works as I wanted. (I'll assume that the problem I encountered was a bug and that they fixed it. ) Thanks to everyone who helped and gave advice in the comments.

Might have been this bug: https://projects.blender.org/blender/blender/pulls/122791
Also note for other outputs the "save_as_render" checkbox in the output node can help achieve the expected colors.
